# NHibernate projections: How to project QueryOver into list of int?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

Trying to project query result into a list of integers. How does one do that? What transformer should be used. AliasToBean does not work as it requires setter.

```
var accessFeeYears = _session.QueryOver<AgreementAccessFee>()
                        .JoinAlias(a => a.FeeType, () => agreementAccessFeeTypeAlias)
                        .Where(x => x.Agreement.Id == request.AgreementId
                                                             && agreementAccessFeeTypeAlias.Code ==AgreementAccessFeeTypeCode.FlatChargePerInsured)
                         .SelectList(list => list
                                        .Select(a => a.PolicyYear).WithAlias(() =>policyYear))
                         .TransformUsing(Transformers.??????)
                         .List<int>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
_session.QueryOver<AgreementAccessFee>()
    .JoinAlias(a => a.FeeType, () => agreementAccessFeeTypeAlias)
    .Where(x => x.Agreement.Id == request.AgreementId
        && agreementAccessFeeTypeAlias.Code == AgreementAccessFeeTypeCode.FlatChargePerInsured)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(a => a.PolicyYear))
    .List<int>();
```

(get rid of the `TransformUsing` all together)

Answer (score 0):

That was easy, after looking at the options, PassThrough looked like it would work, and it did.